# windows azure diagnostics agent stopped working

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

I get this error when I'm trying to start up web role in the emulator in debug mode. Checked this in several machines but the issue is remains the same. Any help will be great? I'm using Visual Studio 2012, Windows Azure SDK 1.7

Comment: Might need more info here.  Do you have stack trace you can add?  Check your Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString setting and ensure the connection string is valid (https, no spaces, etc.)

Comment: Connection string is pointing to development storage, so I think thers nothing wrong there. It's not possible get a stack trace because this error fires up during the startup of the role. And keeps firing up again and again until I kill the debug process.

Comment: Try pointing your diagnostics connection string to a real Azure storage account and not using "UseDevelopmentStorage=true".  If everything starts up okay then something is not right with the set up of the local storage emulator.  If it doesn't start up okay I'd suggest reinstalling the SDK.